# .NET Core Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore ILikeExpression

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am using EntityFramework Core with Npgsql provider, perform ILIKE query works fine:

```
var query = dbContext.countries
                      .Where(w => (w.name != null && 
                               EF.Functions.ILike(w.name, $"{search}%")
                       );
```

Query is translated into PostgreSQL's ILIKE, so far so good.

I am also building a dynamic LINQ based on annotation - [Searchable] or [Orderable] properties in models - and I am trying to find out how to perform ILIKE using Expressions and Lambda. Code:

```
 // works, except it produces just LIKE which is case sensitive. Not enough.
 expr = Expression.Call(property, nameof(string.Contains), new Type[] { }, Expression.Constant(search));

 // does not work, ends with exception, see below
 expr = new Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.Expressions.Internal.ILikeExpression(property, Expression.Constant(search_query));
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
// Exception

Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HLGC19DMS3OI", Request id "0HLGC19DMS3OI:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.ArgumentException: must be reducible node
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ReduceAndCheck()
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ReduceExtensions()
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExtensionExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteLogicalBinaryExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteLogicalBinaryExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteLogicalBinaryExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteLogicalBinaryExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteLogicalBinaryExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpressionFreeTemps(Expression expression, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.Rewrite[T](Expression`1 lambda)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(StackSpiller spiller)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteLambdaExpression(Expression expr)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpressionFreeTemps(Expression expression, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.Rewrite[T](Expression`1 lambda)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(StackSpiller spiller)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteLambdaExpression(Expression expr)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpressionFreeTemps(Expression expression, Stack stack)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.Rewrite[T](Expression`1 lambda)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(StackSpiller spiller)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Compile(Boolean preferInterpretation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateExecutorLambda[TResults]()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateAsyncQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken
cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.CountAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to emit the expression equivalent of the `EF.Functions.ILike(string, string)` call.

`ILike` is a static extension method defined as

```
public static class NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions
{
    public static bool ILike(this DbFunctions _, string matchExpression, string pattern);
}
```

and `Functions` is a static property of the `EF` class

```
public static class EF
{
    public static DbFunctions Functions { get; }
}
```

Hence the expression you are seeking is something like this:

```
expr = Expression.Call(
    typeof(NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions), 
    nameof(NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions.ILike),
    Type.EmptyTypes,
    Expression.Property(null, typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Functions)),
    property,
    Expression.Constant(search)
);
```

Comment: I found this issue on GitHub as well and I was having the same trouble. What I do not understand is how to use the `expr` variable of `Expression.Call()`. Do you include with the linq query - some form of `dbContext.countries.Where(q => expr(q))`?

Comment: @BarrettGay You need to create and use lambda expression from it. e.g. you would have something like `var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Country, "c"); var property = Expression.Property(param, string_property_name); var expr = Expression.Call(…); var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Country, bool>>(expr, param);` and then `var query = dbContext.Countries.Where(predicate);`

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
var _regex = typeof(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex).GetMethod("IsMatch", 
                                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                                null, 
                                new[] { 
                                    typeof(string),  
                                    typeof(string),
                                    typeof(System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions)
                                },
                                null
                                );

                        _expr = Expression.Call(_regex, property, Expression.Constant(search, typeof(string)), Expression.Constant(System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

**EDIT**

Working code:

```
var _ILike = typeof(NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod("ILike", 
                                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                                null, 
                                new[] { 
                                    typeof(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctions),  
                                    typeof(string),  
                                    typeof(string) 
                                },
                                null
                                );

_expr = Expression.Call(
                    _ILike, 
                    Expression.Constant(null, typeof(DbFunctions)), 
                    property, 
                    Expression.Constant(search, typeof(string)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This (Where T class) works:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetCriteriaWhere<T>(string fieldName,  object fieldValue)
{
            PropertyInfo prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(fieldName);

            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            var expressionParameter = GetMemberExpression<T>(parameter, fieldName);

            var _ILike = typeof(NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod("ILike",
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null,
                new[] {
                                    typeof(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctions),
                                    typeof(string),
                                    typeof(string)
                },
                null
                );


            var bodyLike = Expression.Call(_ILike, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(DbFunctions)), expressionParameter, Expression.Constant("%" + fieldValue + "%", typeof(string)));

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(bodyLike, parameter);
}
```

Comment: The only thing that i am not sure why its not working is when you try to search for a % in text. Tried \% but this did not work for me.