# Expression tree with EF.Functions.Like produces error when used in extension method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I can run this method successfully.

```
db.Users.Where(x => arrayOfStringEmail.Any(email => EF.Functions.Like(x.Email, "%" + email + "%")))
```

But when changed to extension method it generates error:

> The LINQ expression 'x => x.Email' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.`

Here's the extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereLike<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, object>> expression, params string[] words)
{
    return source.Where(x => words.Any(word => EF.Functions.Like(expression, "%" + word + "%")));
}
```

I want to use it like

```
db.Users.WhereLike(x => x.Email, arrayOfStringEmail);
```

Comment: How `Email` is mapped to database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How dynamic or usage in EF Core Where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76270256/how-dynamic-or-usage-in-ef-core-where)

Comment: BTW what EF Core version are you using?

Comment: EF Core 8. It works when I don't use it as extension method. Here's where I got https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10834#issuecomment-1841463975

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all [`EF.Functions.Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-8.0) accepts only strings for the `matchExpression` parameter so you can't work with anything but that, so your method signature should reflect that:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereLike<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
    Expression<Func<TSource, string>> expression, // selector should return the string
    string[] words)
```

You need to correctly build the expression tree.

Possibly the easiest approach would be to try to utilize library like [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) and it's `AsExpandable`:

```cs
return source.AsExpandable()
    .Where(x => words.Any(w => EF.Functions.Like(expression.Invoke(x), "%" + w + "%")));
```

But you can try to build needed expressions manually. Something along these lines:

```cs
// to save some reflection manipulations
Expression<Func<string, string, bool>> efLikeSource = (o, s) => EF.Functions.Like(o, "%" + s + "%");
Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> wordsAny = x => words.Any(word => true);

var wordsAnyBody = wordsAny.Body as MethodCallExpression;
var efLikeBody = new ReplacingExpressionVisitor(new[] { efLikeSource.Parameters[0] }, new[] { expression.Body }).Visit(efLikeSource.Body);
var efLikeLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(efLikeBody, efLikeSource.Parameters[1]);
var wordsAnyNewBody = Expression.Call(wordsAnyBody.Method, wordsAnyBody.Arguments.First(), efLikeLambda);
var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(wordsAnyNewBody, expression.Parameters);
return source.Where(result);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it produces same errors.

Comment: Can you please provide a fully runnable [mre]? For example @github?

Comment: It will not work, EF supports only `Contains` with local collections.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv that was my guess too but OP claims that `db.Users.Where(x => arrayOfStringEmail.Any(email => EF.Functions.Like(x.Email, "%" + email + "%")))` works.

Comment: Yes, strange. Maybe we have missed announcement ;)

Comment: EF Core 8. Yes it works without extension method

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10834#issuecomment-1841463975

Comment: @derodevil without [mre] - try swapping parameters `new ReplacingExpressionVisitor(predicate.Parameters, expression.Parameters).Visit(predicate)`

Comment: @GuruStron When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and change it to not visit children of this type.

Comment: @derodevil see the update. Again, without [mre] it is a bit blind but still try it.

Comment: This works but it's only for single `Like`  and accepts string only. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210402/make-dynamic-expression-of-ef-core-like-function

Comment: @derodevil You comment is not very clear. Have you tried the new code?

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, I did. It doesn't work. Same error message. I ask another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77914650/combine-multiple-binaryexpression-with-or

Comment: @derodevil Both approaches? Can you please post a [mre] @github?

Comment: Both approaches didn't work. It's hard for me to do so. It's actually a complex query. But using `LIKE OR LIKE` in simple query resulted the same error.

Comment: @derodevil what is `LIKE OR LIKE`?

Comment: For example, the desired result is like `select name, gender from user where email like '%dean%' or email like '%joan%' `. This works if it's not using extension method `db.Users.Where(x => arrayOfStringEmail.Any(email => EF.Functions.Like(x.Email, "%" + email + "%")))`

Comment: @derodevil can you please create a [mre] containing only the simple working example and non-working original one? What database are you using? MySql? What packages?

Comment: @derodevil both options actually work for me (fixed the LINQKit one since copied wrong iteration previously). `EF.Functions.Like` requires `string` as parameter, so you can't use `object` in your function signature. Updated the answer to fix `object` -> `string` for the manual expression tree manipulation.

Comment: @derodevil added PR with changes.

Comment: @GuruStron how if the property type is not string, like integer, guid or else? This is generic extension method. Well, thank you so much for your help. I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: @derodevil then `EF.Functions.Like` is not applicable either way unless you willing to call `ToString()` on the property but it is better done on the caller side.